# Passing string fields with double quotes from flask to javascript

Tags: javascript, python, json, flask, jinja2

I have been struggling for this simple task:
in the python flask backend I pass this dict to the frontend:

```
data= {"id": "1", "text": "RC 5.5\"/140mm"}
print(data)
print(json.dumps(data))
return render_template("page.html", ..., data=json.dumps(data), ...)
```

At server side, it prints out:

```
{'id': '1', 'text': 'RC 5.5"/140mm'}
{"id": "1", "text": "RC 5.5\"/140mm"}
```

in the javescript, I try to console.log it:

```
console.log(`{{ data| safe }}`);
```

it shows in the console like this:

```
{"id": 1, "text": "RC 5.5"/140mm"}
```

I cannot JSON.parse this:

```
JSON.parse(`{{ row_data | safe }}`)
```

It throws an error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token / in JSON at position 29

Apparently, the middle double quote was not handled (escaped? )

Can anyone help with this please.

Comment: did u tried this: `data= {"id": "1", "text": 'RC 5.5"/140mm'}`

Comment: @SURYATEJA, Yes I have. The printout is exactly the same. :(

Comment: Ok did the following helped? `data= {"id": "1", "text": "RC 5.5\"\/140mm"}`

Answer (score 0):

You want a **raw string**: prefix the string literal with an 'r', and write the
string literal in single quotes (to avoid introducing any more backslashes than
you need):

```
data= {"id": "1", "text": r'RC 5.5\"/140mm'}
```

Becauseof the raw string, python will not interpret the backslash, it will be
present inside the string, so it will be passed on in the render_template
function.